# MongoDB, different collections per user

Tags: mongodb

I am building an application that will have many many different users. Every user will be completely independent from each other (it will be a note-taking app, so each user will have their own notes).

This got me thinking if it would be a good idea to have a separate note collection for each user with a name depending on the user's id. This way, I will have to search in much smaller collections and the whole app would be faster, because I will already have the notes of each user organized in specific collections.

It's worth noting that the note collection is very complicated and has references to other collections, so I prefer it not to be embedded into the users collection itself.

Is this a good idea? Why/why not?

Comment: I think you are confusing the concepts of [collections and documents in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/).

Comment: Why do think so? I really want a different collection per user, aka `notes_0bfe78678634`, `notes_0beef0542634` etc

Comment: Why not a single `notes` collection that contains many documents per user?

Comment: You mean a `notes` collection with a reference to the user, and an array of notes (as an embedded collection)?

Comment: No, as in a `notes` collection that has multiple documents where a typical note document has a field that contains a reference to a `user`, e.g. a sample `note` document may have the structure `{ _id: 'note id here', userId: 'ref to user _id', text: 'the note text here' }`

Comment: But this way we will have to search the whole collection in order to find a specific user's notes. I'm not familiar with benchmarking, that's why I ask. What I'm suggesting, as I think of it, will result in faster searching times, because I will not need to search a very large collection based on the `userId`, but a specific collection that contains all the specific user notes. What's the flaw in this practice?

Comment: MongoDb supports sharding for handling large data sets. If you use a collection per user you will never be able to execute queries for multiple users in one query. You can use the userid as shardkey. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/

Comment: The users are independent... I will never execute a query for more than 1 user at a time...

Comment: @hytromo Several years later, but I'm now facing exactly the same question and your comment "but this way we will have to search the whole collection in order to find a specific user's notes" resonates. What did you end up doing, and do you now have a clearer understanding on the pros and cons?

Comment: The real answer is that we met the typical problem of handling complex queries and transcations with MongoDB so we migrated to PostgreSQL, so this isn't relevant to me anymore. I think it's worth a benchmarking try but I haven't seen anyone do different collections per user. It should complicate things a lot.